# Is there a way to make a desktop shortcut for Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Currently, I access Jupyter notebook by opening Anocanda Navigator then opening the notebook link.  I have tried to bookmark the webpage but most of the time it doesn't work since it is a local page and I think some of the files are still "running" (I am clearly not an expert here and well aware of how stupid this may sound).  Is there any way to have Jupyter Notebook as its own desktop link without having to open it via Anaconda?

Comment: not aware of the desktop link but for faster access I suggest to go through the terminal

Comment: You can usually open it from the command line via `jupyter notebook` but that largely depends on your setup. Can you post more info about your operating system, as well as what do you get when you run `jupyter --version` ?

Comment: Which os are you using?

Answer (score 5):

For Windows, you can create a shortcut pointing to the following path:

```
%PY_HOME%\python.exe %PY_HOME%\cwp.py %PY_HOME% %PY_HOME%\python.exe -m jupyter notebook
```

Where `%PY_HOME%` is my environment variable pointing to the Anaconda folder (example: `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3`). It's useful to use the environment variable because you may run out of characters.

If you want to run a especific environment:

```
%PY_HOME%\python.exe %PY_HOME%\cwp.py %PY_HOME%\envs\myenvironment %PY_HOME%\envs\myenvironment\python.exe -m jupyter notebook
```

Answer (score 3):

You could make a bat file like so and put it in your desktop

start_jupyter.bat

```
:: enable anaconda environment
set root=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
call %root%\Scripts\activate.bat %root%

:: start jupyter
call cd "C:\Users\<USER>\<JUPYTER DOCUMENT ROOT>"
call jupyter notebook

pause
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows, open the search function on your nav bar on the bottom. Type "Jupyter Notebook". It should populate with your notebook. Then, right click on it and select "Open file location". This will take you to the file explorer. Finally, on the Notebook application that you use to run the Jupyter Notebook, right click "Copy". Then go to your desktop, and right click. Select "Paste shortcut", and Eureka! You should have the application shortcut on your desktop.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a text file on your desktop and paste the following line into it:

```
jupyter notebook
```

Then save the file as `Jupyter Notebook.bat` and use it as a shortcut for Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: You're misleading people. Obviously you cannot run `jupyter.py` script without being in the proper python environment, else you get `'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`. You could run `jupyter notebook` command in the conda console (prompt), but that's not what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can launch your jupyter notebook from remote server by trying on cmd prompt:

> jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8080

or run the following command to launch with default port:

> jupyter notebook --no-browser

Comment: '*you can launch your jupyter notebook*', this doesn't open a notebook, this starts nbserver, the http server used to execute notebooks. In addition this cannot start the server unless you have python.exe reachable, which is not the case by default, unless you have switched to the correct folder (the one of your python installation, or the correct conda environment if you use conda. See [this](https://docs.jupyter.org/en/latest/running.html#running-the-notebook).

Answer (score 0):

On linuxmint
[image]
<default_path_to_launcher> = /home/**editUserName**/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook
<launch_in_a_specific_folder> = /home/**editUserName**/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook --notebook-dir /**editPathToDirectory**/

1. By editing main menu

   1.1 Right click menu

   1.2 Select **Configure**

   1.3 Open **Menu** tab

   1.4 In **Layout and content**, at the last, click **Open the menu editor**

   1.5 Select any folder where you want to place the launcher

   1.6 In the right sidebar, select **New Item**

   1.7 In the **Launcher Properties** window, enter following

   ```
       - Name = Jupyter Notebook
       - Command = <path to launcher> or you can <launch in a specific folder>
       - Comment = Open Jupyter Notebook
       - click Icon, search jupyter, select any
       - OK
   ```

   1.8 Now open menu, go to the folder, et voila Jupyter Notebook, click it

   1.9 If it launches, then open menu, go to that folder

   1.10 Right click the launcher

   ```
   - Add to desktop
   - Add to panel
   - Add to favorites
   ```
2. On desktop

   2.1 Right click on desktop

   2.2 Select **+Create new launcher here**

   2.1 Follow step 1.7

**Note 1**: Replace jupyter-notebook with jupyter-lab in commands above, and that will launch jupyter-lab

**Note 2**: Do not edit the launcher using text editors. In my experience this breaks the launcher. Follow steps 1.1 to 1.5, in the right sidebar, click **Properties** to edit command or icon. On desktop, right click the launcher, select **Properties**.

**Note 3**: For **Windows**, creating .bat file [as per this works on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62878838/13627278). You can even remove `call cd` line, and modify next line as `call jupyter notebook --notebook-dir /**editPathToDirectory**/

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script in Python that will launch Jupiter notebook via the command line, and then convert it to an EXE file using the auto-py-to-exe library

```
import os


os.system('jupyter-notebook')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).