# How can I open jupyter in a venv with a shortcut?

Tags: python, windows, powershell, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I installed Jupyter in a virtual environment on Windows 10 using the following Powershell commands:

```
virtualenv --python C:\Path\To\Python\python.exe venv-name
.\venv-name\Scripts\activate
pip install numpy matplotlib jupyter notebook pandas joblib scipy sympy
jupyter notebook
```

I have done absolutely nothing beyond this other than having Python and virtualenv on my computer.
To get into Jupyter notebook, I run lines 2 and 4 of this in Powershell, which works just fine.

How can I achieve the same effect of opening Jupyter notebook using a Desktop/Taskbar shortcut?

I read the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62878573/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-desktop-shortcut-for-jupyter-notebook) question, but both of the useful answers make use of conda and Anaconda, which I do not have, and do not really want to have as it seems like it should be unnecessary for this task.

Comment: Read following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37219045/windows-run-python-command-from-clickable-icon

Comment: Those answers are not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description of how you open Jupyter Notebook from an interactive PowerShell session (lines 2 and 4), you'll need to make your shortcut file call [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, with said statements.

Here's a PowerShell snippet that creates a shortcut file programmatically:

```bash
# Path to the shortcut file; adjust as needed.
$shortcutFile = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Jupyter Notebook.lnk"

# Create the shortcut file...
$shortcut = (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).CreateShortcut($shortcutFile)

# ... and set its properties.

# Specify the target executable and its arguments.
$shortcut.TargetPath = 'powershell.exe' 
$shortcut.Arguments =
  '-NoExit -Command .\venv-name\Scripts\activate; jupyter notebook'

# Specify the working directory.
$shortcut.WorkingDirectory = '%USERPROFILE%'

# Set the window style, if needed.
$shortcut.WindowStyle = 7 # Open the PowerShell console window minimized.

$shortcut.Save()

# Test invocation (simulate opening the shortcut interactively)
Invoke-Item $shortcutFile
```

Note:

- `-NoExit` keeps the PowerShell session open, so you can inspect what happened on startup; you can remove it once you've verified that launching the notebook works as intended.
- **`.WindowStyle = 7`** starts the PowerShell session *minimized* (as you're probably not interested in seeing the console window. Thus, in combination with `-NoExit`, if you want inspect what happened on startup, you'll need to activate the minimized window via the taskbar.
- Assigning to **`.TargetPath`**, i.e. specifying the target executable,  causes the assigned value to be *instantly resolved to a full path*:

  - If you assign a *mere file name* - e.g. `powershell.exe` - it is looked for in the path, i.e. in the directories listed in the standard `$env:PATH` environment variable.

    - *Caveat*: If an executable by that name *happens to exist in the same directory as the shortcut file*, *it* is used.
  - Thus, for full robustness you may want to assign a *full path*, e.g.:

    - With a literal or environment-variable-based path, e.g.:

      ```bash
       .TargetPath = "$env:windir\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
      ```
    - Or, by performing the `$env:PATH` lookup at design time; e.g.:

      ```bash
       .TargetPath = (Get-Command powershell.exe).Path
      ```
- By default, the launched process' working directory is set to:

  - the *directory in which the shortcut file is located* when the shortcut file is opened *interactively* (as is typical; via the taskbar or from the Desktop or from File Explorer)
  - by contrast, in *programmatic* invocation it depends on the *caller's working directory*, with one subtle distinction.

    - with `Invoke-Item`, it is the the working directory of the caller's *process* - which typically differs from *PowerShell's* working directory.<sup>[1]</sup>
    - with `Start-Process`, it is the working directory (location) of the calling *PowerShell session*.
  - Therefore, it is best to *explicitly* assign a working directory, by assigning to the **`.WorkingDirectory`** property.
- As shown in the `.WorkingDirectory` assignment above, **you may use `cmd.exe`-style *environment-variable references*** such as `%USERPROFILE%`, and such references are equally supported in the `.TargetPath`, `.Arguments` and `.IconLocation` properties.
- *General caveat*:

  - Despite its name, the `.CreateShortcut()` method can also open *existing* shortcut files, e.g. to examine their properties.
  - If you (possibly unwittingly) open an *existing* shortcut file during an attempt to fully (re)create it, and only fill in *some* of its properties, any *preexisting* property values are *preserved*.
  - Thus, if the intent is to create a shortcut file *from scratch*, delete any preexisting version first.
- Documentation links:

  - [`WScript.Shell` (`WshShell`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aew9yb99(v=vs.85)) COM object.
  - [`.CreateShortcut()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/xsy6k3ys(v=vs.85)) method.
  - [`WshShortcut`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xk6kst2k.aspx) object.

---

<sup>[1] PowerShell supports multiple runspaces (threads) per process, each of which can have a separate working directory. This contrasts with the *single, process-wide* working directory, as used by .NET and other in-process APIs. Therefore, a given PowerShell session's (runspace's) working directory cannot be kept in sync with the process-wide one, and the two typically *differ*. The upshot is that you should always pass *full, file-system-native* paths to .NET and other in-process APIs. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57791227/45375).</sup>

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Tbw. However, `cd ..` will only work if your shortcut file _happens to be located on your desktop_. `$shortcut.WorkingDirectory = '%USERPROFILE%'` (or `$shortcut.WorkingDirectory = $env:USERPROFILE`) is the more robust solution - please see the updated answer.